# IP Lista Blanca VB NET

Tags: vb.net

Quiero saber como hacer, que mi programa al ser abierto desde una `IP` que ya esta en el código, se pueda, y si no es la misma `IP`, que no se pueda. La parte de que se pueda y no es fácil, pero la variable de la `ip` tipo

```
if ip = (X) then form1.show
```

no se hacerla.

Answer (score 0):

Que tipo de aplicación es? dependiendo de aquello tienes muchas opciones. Por ejemplo si es Web, probablemente puedas capturar del Request la IP que hace la solicitud (Aunque esto lo puedes hacer desde el IIS).

Ahora si es de Consola o de Escritorio o WPF puedes capturar la IP Local y con esa hacer tu validación. Algo asi:

```html
public static string GetLocalIPAddress()
{
    var host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
    foreach (var ip in host.AddressList)
    {
        if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
        {
            return ip.ToString();
        }
    }
    throw new Exception("No network adapters with an IPv4 address in the system!");
} 

if (GetLocalIPAddress() == "ipPermitida") 
  //TODO Lo que quieras hacer
```

Comment: es visual basic, windows forms